# My font changes the height of my tabular row, how could I fix that?

Tags: tables, fonts, height

The height of my row changes according to the font I use on. 
I have a problem with the φ or ψ letters for example, they make the height of row bigger.

As you can see on the image under, rows with the φ letter are much bigger than others, you can check that on the sides by the placement of the small numbers.
We can see blanks spaces separating rows.

[image: Matthew 1:11]

So, can someone help me to have not anymore that blanks spaces separating rows please ?

I know that if the height of row with φ is the same than classic row then a part of the φ should go over the row under.
But this is not a problem for me, it's the result I expect.

Here is my MWE code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setotherlanguage{greek}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{FreerFont Smooth}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{cc|l|cc}
\cline{3-3}
\textbf{18} &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{του δε ιυ η γενεϲειϲ ουτωϲ ην} & 7 & \\
& 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{μνηϲτευθειϲηϲ γαρ τηϲ μητροϲ αυ} & 12 &  \\
& 12 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{του μαριαϲ τω ιωϲηφ πριν η ϲυνελ} & 18 &  \\
& 18 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{θειν αυτουϲ ευρεθη εν γαϲτρι εχου} & 23 &  \\
\cline{3-3}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Thanks !

Comment: Try `\def\arraystretch{2.0}`, or at least some number larger than 1.0.  Make it local to the table environment.

Comment: Your solution makes the height of row bigger, but I'd like them to be normal. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not have your font, so I had to try to simulate it.

What I am doing is putting your line into a box and smashing its vertical size, so the size of the table line is fixed (basically by the numbers in the other columns). In my greek font the φ is better behaved, so I added a couple of huge math parenthesis to simulate the overlap.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,array}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setotherlanguage{greek}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\let\endslap\relax
\def\slap#1\endslap{%
    \raisebox{0pt}[0.0cm][0pt]{\hbox{#1}}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{cc|>{\slap}l<{\endslap}|cc}
\cline{3-3}
\textbf{18} &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{του δε ιυ η γενεϲειϲ ουτωϲ ην} & 7 & \\
& 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{μνηϲτευθειϲηϲ γαρ τηϲ μητροϲ αυ} & 12 &  \\
& 12 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{του μαριαϲ τω {\Huge $()$} ιωϲηφ πριν η ϲυνελ} & 18 &  \\
& 18 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{θειν αυτουϲ ευρεθη εν γαϲτρι εχου} & 23 &  \\
\cline{3-3}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(you can also change the `0.0cm` in the definition of `slap` to have a fixed size).

Comment: Very nice. Approved it.